# How to prevent bootstrap version collisions using shadow dom

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, shadow-dom

Hello everyone hope you're all having a good day.

I'm making a web component that uses bootstrap 5. Since the shadow DOM is supposed to encapsulate styling I assumed that it would be a good way to prevent it from colliding with any sites that might be using older versions of bootstrap (since they tend to have the same class name). I feel like I'm missing something obvious, but whenever I include other versions of bootstrap in the html document they override what's in my component. I've been stuck on it for a few days now and haven't found anything to explain why this might be.

```html
const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHtml = `
  <style>@import "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" </style>
  <div class="container">
    <p>All my web component stylings go on from here and use bootstrap classes as well</p>
  </div>
`

class MyWebComponent extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super();
    var shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
    shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
  }
}
window.customElements.define('my-web-component', MyWebComponent);
```

And my index.html file is simply

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="link to bootstrap3 or boostrap4.css" />
  <script type="module" src="linkToMyWebComponent"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <my-web-component />
</body>
```

I've noticed that if I manually define styles within the template html like

```html
<style>.form-control { p: 10 }</style>
```

that it works just fine and overwrites all the stylings. Any help, or learning material would be much appreciated. Although feel like I've read at least two dozen long articles about templates, shadow dom, etc. on it at this point. The flattened shadow dom looks like it should be encapsulated from the older scripts, but no luck.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Bootstrap was never developed with shadowDOM in mind; its like trying to put petrol gas in a Tesla

Comment: Regardless, I'm confused as to something like that still wouldn't work without issue. Since I can download the bootstrap5.css and run it as a local reference just fine, and I can also import external css scripts into the shadow dom, what is stopping the shadow dom from simply importing and using bootstrap?

Comment: Go file an issue with Bootstrap

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman I did go ahead and open up a discussion on the bootstrap github project. Regardless of if this was bootstrap, or any other generic library, shouldn't importing **any** sort of external stylesheet (like if I had created one on my own) be encapsulated within the shadow DOM? Or am I fundamentally misunderstanding how importing stylesheets work in the shadow DOM?